# How do I translate "hangover"?

Tags: translation, single-word-requests

How do I translate **hangover** in Esperanto? Is there a single word to translate it?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the purpose of Stack Exchange if you ask a question like this here. Even google translate gets "postebrio" right.

Comment: @JaneDChen I did it, anyway I know word **hangover** there isn't in some languages (You can't say it with just 1 word), so I asked it here.

Comment: **Postebrio** in reta-vortaro.de; Dutch kater, German Kater.

Answer (score 6):

Mi ĉiam diris *postebria malsano*, sed se vi volas unu vorton mi dirus *postebrio*.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest *postdrinka kapdoloro* or *postebrio*.

Comment: *Postebrio* is the one I use and always hear.

Comment: *Postdrinka kapdoloro* is not so clear, as it could also be a headache that you have directly after drinking. *Postebria kapdoloro*, on the other hand, is a good, more explicit alternative to the common *postebrio*.

Answer (score 1):

I usually hear *postebria sindromo*, or sometimes (in informal language) *hesako*, from the Portuguese *ressaca*.